# checkbox values separated by "," and "and"

Tags: jquery

I want checkbox values to be separated by "," and "and", I have 3 checkboxes and I want to show those values in a div. Like for example if a person choose to value one it will be just one value, if selected values are two then it will be separated by value1 "and" value2 and if three values then value1 "," value2 "and" value 3

```js
$(".selective").change(function(e) {
   var ValForDiv='';
   var length = $('input.selective:checked').length;
   var i=0;
   $('input.selective:checked').each(function () {
    i++;
    var ThisVal = $(this).val();
    if(i == 1){
     ValForDiv += ThisVal;
    }
    else if(i == length){
     ValForDiv += ThisVal + ' , ';
    }
    else if(i == length - 1){
     ValForDiv += ThisVal + ' and ';
    }
    else{
     ValForDiv += ' , ' + ThisVal.val();
    }
   });
   $('.causinginjuriestospan').html(ValForDiv);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label upperlowerback">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="chkforspcinjtoupper" type="checkbox" class="selective" name="chkforspcinjtoupper" value="upper"/>
                    <i></i> 
                    <span>Upper</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="chkforspcinjtomiddle" type="checkbox" class="selective" name="chkforspcinjtomiddle" value="middle" />
                    <i></i> 
                    <span>Middle</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="chkforspcinjtolower" type="checkbox" class="selective" name="chkforspcinjtolower"  value="lower"/>
                    <i></i> 
                    <span>Lower</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="causinginjuriestospan"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you increase your `i` value at the start of the callback function, it's basically 1-based instead of 0-based, so you have to check for `i == length` instead of `i == length - 1`. Also, you want to add the comma in front of the term for the `else` case:

```js
$(".selective").change(function(e) {
   var ValForDiv='';
   var length = $('input.selective:checked').length;
   var i=0;
   $('input.selective:checked').each(function () {
    i++;
    var ThisVal = $(this).val();
    if(i === 1){
     ValForDiv += ThisVal;
    }
    else if(i == length){
     ValForDiv += ' and ' + ThisVal;
    }
    else{
     ValForDiv += ', ' + ThisVal;
    }
   });
   $('.causinginjuriestospan').html(ValForDiv);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label upperlowerback">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="chkforspcinjtoupper" type="checkbox" class="selective" name="chkforspcinjtoupper" value="upper"/>
                    <i></i> 
                    <span>Upper</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="chkforspcinjtomiddle" type="checkbox" class="selective" name="chkforspcinjtomiddle" value="middle" />
                    <i></i> 
                    <span>Middle</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input id="chkforspcinjtolower" type="checkbox" class="selective" name="chkforspcinjtolower"  value="lower"/>
                    <i></i> 
                    <span>Lower</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="causinginjuriestospan"></div>
```

Comment: Note that first argument of `each` callback is the index also

Comment: Yup, I didn't want to change the code too much (you'd also normally want to put the selected elements into a variable and then use `length` and `each` on that).

Comment: Thank you so much Connum, I got the idea.